# Перегрузка оператора. Сложение дробей

Tags: c++

Изменяю код, в расчёте, может быть кому-нибудь пригодится.
Задача:
Даны две дроби a/b и c/d.

Создайте класс Fraction, который будет хранить дробь вида x/y.
На вход: 2/3  4/5 
Ответ: 22/15

PS Задачи сократить дробь нет. Надо только ввести две обыкновенные дроби с клавиатуры, сложить их и вывести ответ в виде также обыкновенной дроби. Цель продемонстрировать перегрузку операторов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

typedef long long int ll_int;

class Fraction{
    ll_int x, y;
public:
    Fraction(ll_int x = 0, ll_int y =1): x(x),y(y){}
    void read();      // Ввод обыкновенных дробей с клавиатуры                
    void show();      // Вывод результата суммы дробей.        
    Fraction operator +(Fraction &);   //Перегрузка оператора +
};

void Fraction::read(){
    char s;
    cin >> x >> s >> y;     //х  - числитель, s - "/", у - знаменатель   
}

void Fraction::show(){
    cout << x << "/" << y;           //х  - числитель, "/", у - знаменатель
}

Fraction Fraction::operator +(Fraction &v){        
    x = x * v.y + v.x * y;   //Сложение числителей первого и второго числа
    y = y * v.y;
    return *this;
}

int main(){
    Fraction a, b, c;
    a.read();
    b.read();
    c = a + b;
    c.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю что тут вы делаете. У вас объявлены операции вида дробь плюс число, но я не вижу операцию дробь плюс дробь. Да и в том, что есть тоже какая-то ересь. Откуда в сложении взялся new_x, например?

Comment: Что такое `x.v` и `y.v` в реализации опрератора `*`?

Comment: Сейчас напишу комментарии в коде, что я хотел сделать.

Comment: x.v и y.v числитель и знаменатель второй дроби.

Comment: Нет необходимости дописывать в заголовок "Задача решена" и т.п. Как только вы ставите галочку на ответе, сайт сам помечает вопрос как решенный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас уже есть замечания в комментариях. Вот мои:

1. Функции  `read` и `show` полностью специализированы  на консоль.  В
   общем случаи, правильнее, если  они будут получать в аргумент 
   обьект потока. `read(std::istream&)` и `show(std::ostream&)`. Также, можно
   вместо этого определять операторы  `>>`  и  `<<`.
2. Вы совсем не пытаетесь сокращать дробь, а это логичный ход для этого
   класса.
3. Методы, которые не модифицируют обьект и могут не иметь  доступ к закрытым и защищенным членам и  не являются друзьями
   класса, лучше определять вне класса. Например, ваш класс может иметь
   `operator *=`, а  `operator *` можете определить (с его помощью) вне
   класса.
4. Вы неправильно определяете операторы. Например, как нужно умножить
   две дроби на бумаге, думаю знаете, но что вы написали в
   операторе умножения, не понятно...

Вы хотите(в программе) дробь умножить(сложить) на дробь, а не на число. Поэтому:

```
typedef long long int ll_int;
class Fraction{
    ll_int x, y;
public:
    Fraction(ll_int x = 0, ll_int y =1): x(x),y(y){}
    void read();      // Ввод обыкновенных дробей с клавиатуры
    Fraction& operator *=(const Fraction&);
    Fraction& operator +=(const Fraction&);
    void show() const;
};

void Fraction::read()
{
    using std::cin;
    cin >> x;        //пытаемся вводить числитель
    if (cin) {      //если ввод был нормальным, продолжаем
        if (cin.peek() == '/') {  //если следующий символ...
            cin.ignore();         // пропускаем
            cin >> y;
        }
        else     // если нет  символа '/'
            y = 1;
    }
}
// *= и += стоит реализовать для удобства использования класса
Fraction& Fraction::operator *=(const Fraction& f)
{
    x *= f.x;
    y *= f.y;
    return *this;
}
Fraction& Fraction::operator +=(const Fraction& f)
{
    x = x * f.y + y * f.x;
    y *= f.y;
    return *this;
}

void Fraction::show()  const
{
    cout << x << "/" << y;
}
// и вне класса уже можем определять + и *
Fraction operator *(Fraction& f1, const Fraction& f2)
{ return f1 *= f2; }
Fraction operator +(Fraction& f1, const Fraction& f2)
{ return f1 += f2; }
main()
{    
    Fraction a, b, c;
    a.read();
    b.read();
    c = a + b;
    c.show();
     cout << endl;
   // Так как оператор *= возвращает ссыльку на этот обьект
   // можем сразу выполнить и умножение и вывод
    (a *= b).show();
    return 0;
}
```

**Обновление**:

`Fraction Fraction::operator +(ll_int v){...}` Это определение оператора, суммирующая дробь с числом(обьектом  `v` типа  `long` `long`) . Обьект  v  не содержится в вашем классе, поэтому x = x * `y.v` + `x.v` * y; это ошибка. Если хотите, чтобы операнд был не дробью, а  так, как вы пытаетесь, то нужно сделать то же самое, как я вам показал, с разницей, что `знаменатель равен 1`:

```
Fraction Fraction::operator +(ll_int v)
{   
    Fraction  f;   // значения по умолчанию f.x == 0 и f.y == 1     
    f.x = x  + v * y;  
    f.y = y;          
    //так как нет дроби (`v` - это целое число)
    return f;
}
```

Comment: Задачи сократить дробь нет. Надо только ввести две обыкновенные дроби с клавиатуры, сложить их и вывести ответ в виде также обыкновенной дроби. Цель продемонстрировать перегрузку операторов.

Comment: Ну, как хотите.  Я внес изменения

Comment: 1. Мне и нужно вывод в консоль.

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад помочь одногоднику

Comment: AR Hovsepyan, а не могли бы Вы помочь с перегрузкой именно в моём коде. Поправил мелкие огрехи. Не смотрите на ввод и вывод. Не могу понять, почему неправильно?

Comment: Ну если вам нужно именно так, примите доболнение в ответе. Но тогда вы можете дробь суммировать только с целым

Comment: Очень Вам благодарен за помощь!